# Is it possible to return a value from a promise notify callback?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to return anything from a promise `notify` callback?

In the following code `ServiceB.Start` returns a deferred promise where the deferred is defined on `ServiceB`:

```
ServiceB.Start(action).then(
         function() {console.log("Success");},
         function() {console.log("Failed");},
         function (notifyObject) {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             //do something time consuming
             $timeout(function() {
                 if (notifyObject.success) {
                     deferred.resolve({ message: "This is great!" });
                 } else {
                     deferred.reject({ message: "Really bad" });
                 }
             }, 5000);
             console.log(notifyObject.message);
             return deferred.promise;
         }
);


var notifyReturnValue = ServiceB.deferred.notify(notifyObject);
notifyReturnValue.then(
           function() {
             //do something else
             ServiceB.deferred.resolve(data);
           }
        );
    }
```

`notifyReturnValue` seems to be undefined. Is there a way to return something from a `deferred.notify()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return a value from `notify` callback. It works similar to returning value from success/error callbacks. **The returned value is passed on to the next `notify` callback in line.** However, as [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) states, you cannot influence resolution/rejection from `notify` callback. This makes sense, because `notify` may be called multiple times, while a promise may be resolved/rejected only once.

When you call `then`, you get a new `Promise`. That is because it's a means of *chaining* asynchronous actions. The new promise is resolved when not only the original action, but also the callbacks passed into `then` (which can be asynchronous as well) are resolved.

[See this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyJoPx?editors=101) of passing on notification values (with your console open).

Comment: The deferred.resolve I am calling inside notify is a local deferred defined within notifyCallback itself and not the one on which the notify is called. And it is this local deferred.promise i am trying to return back. But guess what i am trying to do wont work as the return value will be passed to the next notify callback in line only. I could chain all my promises together. However i was trying to encapsulates responsibilities to different controllers and not mix them up.

Comment: Notification channel is simply a way of notifying a listener of action progress. It shouldn't be used for anything else. Use other patterns (like events) for other interaction between your components.